# Drawing a class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have been given the class names, properties, and methods. [image: Class]

I'm not sure what the relationships are between them, so I'd appreciate it if someone can correct me below before I start drawing:

Games has a one to many relationship to Sport. Sport has a one to many relationship with Event.
Event has a one to many relationship with Race.

And Heat and Final are subclasses of Race.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have sounds like a pretty good foundation - I think you've captured the relationships pretty well. It seems to me to more of a data model than a class model *per sé*.

To fill your class diagram out, ask yourself the following questions:

- What information do I want to be accessible from outside the system?
- Who (or which class) is responsible for retrieving and collating this information? Should I be able to access Events directly, or should I access them via the Sport they belong to?
- What questions should each class be able to answer about the information it knows? Then provide methods that answer those questions.

Post your solution in the question so we can see what you come up with :)